# Install SP2013 Eng first and then Language pack, or vice versa?

Tags: search, language-pack

My requirement is to provide English and Chinese on the SP2013 site. In my test environment, I installed English SP2013 as base and then install Chinese language pack. The search is not working so well (crawler keep identify some Chinese as English)

I wonder will it make any different if I install Chinese SP2013 as base and then install English language pack?

Answer (score 0):

**Search site templates**
Many of the Search site limitations are not actually related to MUI features, but are architectural designs that affect the user interface. The following limitations are a mix of MUI and architectural limitations for Search sites:

- Search   Search indexes content in the default language of the
  SharePoint Server installation. Even if content is provided in
  alternate languages, that content is only searchable by using the
  default site language. For example, if your preferred language is
  German, and the default site language is English, a search for
  "Freigegebene Dokumente" returns no results. A search for "Shared
  Documents" does return results.

Source : [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805087(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805087%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

So If you need search functionality in the Chinese then you need base installation in Chinese then install the English LP.

Comment: The article seems talking about the search of "site templates" only? Anyway, I will have a try at weekend and feedback. Thanks

Comment: yes that's true but the text i mentioned its basically architectural designs of the search...which is cause your issue.